# Converting a result to a list

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, servicenow

I need your help to convert a result of a ServiceNow API request to a list.
The result shows like following:

```json
"json": {
            "result": {
                "success": "True",
                "entries": {
                    "matches": 119,
                    "records": [
                        {
                            "our_reference": "INV01567761"
                        },
                        {
                            "our_reference": "INV01134545"
                        },
                        {
                            "our_reference": "INV01345435"
                        },
                        {
                            "our_reference": "INV01345345"
                        }
                     ]
```

**What I need is just the value in the dict in a list form like:
`["INV01567761","INV01567761","INV01567761","INV01567761"]`**

to get the list of the records field I choose:

```yaml
- name: trying to get a list
  set_fact:
    incidentList: "{{ ticketresult.json.result.entries.records }}"
- debug: var=incidentList
```

output:

```
[
                        {
                            "our_reference": "INV01567761"
                        },
                        {
                            "our_reference": "INV01134545"
                        },
                        {
                            "our_reference": "INV01345435"
                        },
                        {
                            "our_reference": "INV01345345"
                        }
                     ]
```

but then I'm lost....
I tried several things to extract the numbers from this dict, but getting always the error message because this dict is sitting in a list.
so I tried:

```
ticketresult.json.result.entries.records[0]
```

to get the dict in the list, but this returned only the first item in the dict:

```
{ "our_reference": "INV01567761" }
```

Is there an easy way to get out all the info in **list-form**?

Comment: In the meantime I tried also:
- name: create dict list variable 2
              set_fact:
                incidentList: "{{ incidentList|default([]) + [{item | regex_search('INV[0-9]{8}')}] }}"
              with_items:
                - "{{ ticketresult.json.result.entries.records }}"

but this produces only an error message:
fatal: [usxxx.eu]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {{ incidentList|default([]) + [{item | regex_search('INV[0-9]{8}')}] }}"}

Comment: Please do not add details/code needed to answer your question in comments: [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

The expression below

```yaml
  references: "{{ json.result.entries.records|
                  map(attribute='our_reference')|list }}"
```

gives the list

```yaml
  references:
    - INV01567761
    - INV01134545
    - INV01345435
    - INV01345345
```

Comment: thank you. I was not aware that this structure is a map. great and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    list_of_tickets: "{{ list_of_tickets|default([]) + [item|string|regex_search('INV[0-9]{8}')] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ticketresult.json.result.entries.records }}"
```